# How to extend the Image plugin in ckeditor5 with custom elements?

Tags: ckeditor5

We're evaluating an upgrade from ckeditor 4 to the new ckeditor 5, but I need to be able to extend the Image plugin/package with some custom elements, e.g. a text input for licensing information about the image, a button/checkbox for toggling the image to be a thumbnail or not etc.

How can I add these custom elements in the image package and write my own javascript code to handle the values from these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image toolbar is being controlled by the [`config.image.toolbar`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_image_image-ImageConfig.html#member-toolbar) property. It accepts names of UI components registered in the [`editor.ui.components` factory](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_componentfactory-ComponentFactory.html). In other words, it works like the main editor toolbar which is configurable via `editor.toolbar` and you can learn more how to create buttons here: [Creating a simple plugin](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html#creating-a-simple-plugin).